# replace '?' with Nan or zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have one coluknn of my data which is:

```
Power:
0     130
1     165
2     150
3     150
4     ?
5     198
6     220
7     215
8     225
9     ?
10    170
```

and I want to replace every '?' with Nan or zero.

I tried:

```
data['Power'].str.replace('?', 0).astype(float)
data['Power'].str.replace('^[^\d]*', '').astype(float)
data['Power'].replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
data['Power'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data['Power'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
```

but none of these works!

Some produce an error `could not convert string to float` and some didn't produce any errors but did not change the '?'.

Comment: What does the `data` variable look like?

Comment: Your first attempt would have worked if 0 were a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need replace only all non numeric values to `NaN` use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
data.Power = pd.to_numeric(data.Power, errors='coerce')
print (data)
    Power
0   130.0
1   165.0
2   150.0
3   150.0
4     NaN
5   198.0
6   220.0
7   215.0
8   225.0
9     NaN
10  170.0
```

If need `0` then add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with cast to `int`:

```
data.Power = pd.to_numeric(data.Power, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (data)
    Power
0     130
1     165
2     150
3     150
4       0
5     198
6     220
7     215
8     225
9       0
10    170
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# to replace with 0
df.Power = df.Power.replace(to_replace='?', value = 0)
# to replace with NaN
import numpy as np
df.Power = df.Power.replace(to_replace='?', value = np.nan)
```

Comment: help me improve this answer? I thought I answered the title of the question well

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this instead :

```
data['Power'].apply(lambda s: eval(str(s).replace('?', '0')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Power':[130,165,150,'?',198,220,215,225,'?',170]
                   })  

df.where(df.Power != '?', 0)
```

output:

```
  Power
0   130
1   165
2   150
3     0
4   198
5   220
6   215
7   225
8     0
9   170

df.where(df.Power != '?', 'foo')
```

output

```
  Power
0   130
1   165
2   150
3   foo
4   198
5   220
6   215
7   225
8   foo
9   170
```

works with pretty much anything, and it says in the docs that it's fast. 
[The where() Method and Masking](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/indexing.html)